# Probability distribution of a linear function of a continuous random variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

If $X$ is a continuous random variable, under what condition does the following relation hold true?

$$\mathbb{P}(X < k)  = \mathbb{P}(aX+b < ak +b)$$

Is the above relation dependent on the PDF of $X$?

Comment: Provided $a>0$, $X<k$ iff $aX+b<ak+b$, so it should always be true (in both continuous or discrete situations)

Comment: nope, just a>0 is the condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elaborating on @Michael Burr's comment, if $a>0$ then for any $\omega$,

$$X(\omega) < k \iff aX(\omega) + b < ak + b,$$
so
$$\{X < k\} = \{aX + b < ak + b\} $$
and hence
$$\mathbb P\{X < k\} = \mathbb P\{aX + b < ak + b\}.$$

Answer (score 1):

When $a$ is a positive number.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @user37238:  I realize that the above Comment was auto-generated, but the Answer is correct.  Ken Dunn could of course provide an explanation, in particular addressing the issue of whether the outcome depends on the PDF of $X$, and thereby greatly improve the Answer.